# My DSi goes blank after the health and safety message - How can I fix it?

Tags: technical-issues, nintendo-dsi

My Nintendo DSI is not working. When I try to turn it on, the health and safety screen comes on for a second and then the screen goes black, even though the power and Wi-Fi light are still on.

I have been experiencing this problem since I was on a plane and my D.S.I. would not work. At the time I just thought it was the plane, but after I landed it still wouldn't work.

It has not been dropped, damaged or wet and it is fully charged. How can I fix this problem?

I have taken the battery out->put it back in and it works sometimes (for a little while), but then it stops working again. I would like a more permanent solution.

Comment: If it stopped working after a plane ride, it might have been damaged from the change in air pressure; this is not normal (I've had a DSi survive 4 plane flights with absolutely no trouble). If you're still under warranty, this would be a good time to use it.

Comment: So, we can at least say the display works. After the health info screen, does the screen completely turn off, or does it just go black while backlit (i.e. it looks different than when turned off)? Either way, my guess would either something wrong with the operational system of the DS, or a mechanical failure causing the same thing (Judging from the state in which the DS fails).

Comment: @Humungus it looks as if it has been turned off except for the blue power light and the yellow Wi-Fi light.

Comment: @Oreo Huh... that is strange. I'm afraid I can't offer any more advice, besides asking some game shop on where you might get it fixed.

Answer (score 1):

With your power supply plugged in, do you see the central orange LED light up? If not, you have a power supply issue and no charge is getting to your battery. A severely depleted battery needs to reach a relatively high level of charge before the device will boot. Half an hour charge probably isn't even enough, so be sure to leave it for over an hour when dealing with very low battery levels.